How to do olympic lifts in a commercial gym?
In most videos I see of any olympic lift, it seems so that the barbell is dropped right after the lift finishes. Is there anyway to do it without dropping freely to the floor? I am searching for guides which explain how to catch the barbell on your thighs but I can't find any.

You don't need to drop the barbell all the time to train olympic lifts. After you snatch and clean (barbell above your head) simply HOLD onto the barbell while lowering it and it will catch on your thighs, then you lower it to the floor in a controlled motion. Basically the reverse of the movement to bring the bar up. There's not much more than that.
On the other hand, you CAN drop the barbell - in some gyms. Check Clarence's video where he talks about training in commercial gyms (he also do quite a few reps doing exactly what you're asking: not dropping the barbell). Basically:

opt for what he calls a "performance gym": a crossfit gym or powerlifting gym, if you can find those they have weightlifting platforms and bumper plates and you'll not gonna get looks for dropping the bar.
some regular gyms have platforms and bumper plates. I go to a franchise gym near my house, and they have both.

